# Java - SQL - Getting everything from the database and outputting it

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get everything I have in my database *(see below for a picture of it)* and output it out the the user.

[PICTURE OF HOW MY DATABASE LOOKS!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6PmK.png)

### For example:

ID: 1
Name: bob
Area: 1
Date: 3/11
Message: hi

ID: 2
Name: larry
Area: 3
Date: 6/9
Message: hello

etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: select * from yourtablename.  Otherwise if you want someone to write your java for you you've got about a 50/50 chance of having that happen.

Comment: @MikeS I know that, but I dont understand how after I got all the stuff from the database to display it.

Comment: I mean look at a technical document or a tutorial.  Oracle makes a bunch of them for Java related programming.  Just like this one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html.

Comment: Based on the tags you have a MYSQL Database. You will want to acquire the JDBC Driver for MYSQL and implement the library into you Java project. Make a connection to the Database then with the sql SELECT statement get all specific table records into a result set (ArrayList). It's really not that difficult. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that by database, you mean table because your image shows a table. The standard command to print out an entire table as it is is:

```
select * from [tablename];
```

If you only want to select certain columns, replace the * with the name of the columns.

You should refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html for more information about pulling the data in Java.